# jQuery ajax WCF cross domain

Tags: jquery, ajax, wcf, cross-domain

So I have a basic WCF service to be consumed by straight jQuery/HTML, no asp.net.

I can make GET calls to my test.svc/test via the browser and get my expected JSON result.
**{"d":["test1","test2","test3"]}**

Now, I'm trying to consume it via jQuery 1.4.x

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        url: methodUrl,
        data: {},
        beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
            XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        },
        success: successCallback,
        error: failedCallback
    });
```

I'm grabbing the error info and dumping it to the console, this is my error.
LOG: {"readyState":4,"status":0,"statusText":"error"} 
LOG: "error" 
LOG: {"message":"Access is denied.\r\n","description":"Access is denied.\r\n","number":-2147024891}

I've read that I need to use JSON-P and/or crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled or 30 other things.

So far I've not seen a consistent solution to this problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!
Jon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it appears to be a hack for our situation regardless.

We're using MS Dynamics CRM 2011, which only allows plain html pages with JS and only supports IE.

We ended up running another WCF service that sits on the same box as CRM (breaking requirements) that is just a proxy that in-turn calls our real WCF service that sits on another box.

It's goofy and adds more overhead to maintenance but we're at least able to keep producing JSON instead of JSON-P so that other consumers can use it too.